# Tiling of a $2n \times 2n$ board

Tags: tiling, tessellations

Is there a way to tile a $2n \times 2n$ square with dominoes such that two rectangles cannot be partitioned and slide along each other (interlocking)? I was able to show that for $2 \times 2$ and $4 \times 4$ boards, there is no interlocking, but for a $6 \times 6$ grid there were too many options to do via proof by exhaustion. Doing this on an $8 \times 8$ board and so on would be too much, so I was wondering if there were any good ways to approach this?

Comment: I think this article by Ron Graham https://math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/81_01_fault_free_tilings.pdf might be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Example of an interlocking tiling for the $8\times 8$ board.

[image]